# Images look all messed up on explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

If you visit www.elevatetoronto.com with chrome or firefox everything looks fine. And everything looks fine on Internet explorer as well, however, the images are so thin no one can see them. The images use the same class as the ones on the limo page which turns up fine on ie.

I don't know what's wrong. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What does MySQL have to do with this?

Comment: You'll get a much better response if you create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/) rather than asking us to wade through your website. In addition, placing the code here will help ensure that this question will be useful to users in the future.

Comment: You img heights look like they're set to "" in the markup and explorer is re-interpreting that to be "1", which is overriding any css you might be applying to it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems IE takes an empty image width attribute (`width` or `width=""`) and changes it to `width="1"`

Also why do you have an empty witdh attribute in you image tags 
 Removing them does the trick.

Comment: Thank you sir. I didn't think it would matter but I'll change it